# Vue3 Transition mode don't work inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Offcial Transition mode example just works when v-if&v-else-if block rather than v-if&v-if.

```
<div v-show="docState" class="dio">
  <div class="nav-panel">
    <Transition v-for="doc in docList" name="slide-up" mode="out-in">
      <button v-if="doc === docState">{{doc}}</button>
    </Transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L77IC.gif)

I want to apply transition when switching content instead of setting position to absolute. I tried transition-group outside v-for but transition-group don't support mode prop.

[online demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I understand how you've got to this point but it's generally not a good idea to use Transition in this way.
It would be better to either:

1. Use a transition-group around a loop (which doesn't support mode as you've said)
2. Remove the v-for entirely and bind the button state to the :key attribute.

Using the key atribute causes Transition to treat each unique key as a seperate component and transition between them. You can see in the example that this allows you to use mode as normal and simplifies the template as well.

[:key transition demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution: add a hook to the transition.

1. Setting element style in the @before-enter hook
2. Use the "GSAP library" to animate elements in the @enter or @after-enter hook.

Because GSAP can animate in order, you can avoid element position conflict.
[GSAP library](https://greensock.com/get-started/)